# Can I use my laptop ram, ssd and hdd in desktop motherboard?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, memory, ssd, motherboard

I have an asus rog g531gt, it come with i7 9th gen processor with 4gb invidia GTX 1650ti and 8+8gb ddr4 vram, 512gb PCIE ssd with 1tb hdd(Sata).

Now it's motherboard got damaged, and I want to buy a desktop and use my laptop parts in desktop motherboard,can I use my laptop's ram, ssd, and hdd in desktop motherboard?
If "no" then why?

Comment: "It depends"… mainly on form factor. The RAM is very unlikely to fit. SSD & HD should, but may need adaptors.

Comment: The Memory is not likely to work as it is a different physical size in the equipment I have used. SSD and HDD should work if proper interfaces exist.    If "no" then why?  - you may wish to open your laptop and take a look.

Comment: As everyone is pointing out.. the ram is a different form factor.  There are adapters to allow you to use SO-DIMM ram in a DIMM slot.  Search the google for "so-dimm to dimm adapter ddr4"

Answer (score 1):

HDD: No problem.
SSD: Maybe, depends on if it is a NVMe SSD (not soldered onto the laptop motherboard) en if the new motherboard has a slot for that (most new motherboards do).

RAM: Most likely not. Laptops typically use so-called SO-DIMM ram while desktops use DIMM ram. Different form-factors. It won't physically fit even though the type of RAM (DDR-4) is the same.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I know they exist and they are very risky to use. I can NOT recommend them. RAM timing (especially on DDR4) is very tight and such converters increase wire-lenght between motherboard and RAM on the DIMMs. As a result of that they can add a severely increased risk of random bit-errors to every RAM operation. That will lead to stability issues with the computer (random crashes) and possible data-corruption.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas  Odds are that new motherboard will expect faster DRAM timing.  If the OP is asking here, I'm not sure they have knowledge to benefit from adapters.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat That too.